Template to return vector of elements
I'm trying to write a template that returns a vector of elements of specific type. Unfortunately I'm encountering warnings and errors that I am finding hard to resolve. I suspect I might need to use std::enable_if rather than std::is_same_v, but not sure of the correct way to go about it.
Below is a simplified example that reproduces the issue.
I would appreciate if someone could explain why I get the warnings and errors and how to best resolve them.
Thanks!
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Person
{
    std::string name;
    double age;
    char gender;

    template<class T>
    std::vector<T> GetValue()
    {
        std::vector<T> v;

        if (std::is_same_v<T, double>)
            v.push_back(age);
        if (std::is_same_v<T, char>)
            v.push_back(gender);
        if (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
            v.push_back(name);

        return v;
    }   
};

int main()
{
    Person p{ "Joe", 33, 'm' };
    
    std::vector<double> v1 = p.GetValue<double>();
    std::cout << "double: " << v1[0] << std::endl;

    // Warning with next line
    std::vector<char> v2 = p.GetValue<char>();
    std::cout << "char: " << v2[0] << std::endl;

    // Error with next line
    std::vector<std::string> v3 = p.GetValue<std::string>();
    std::cout << "string: " << v3[0] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}


Please [edit] and add the errors/warning verbatim (as text) to you question. Also: did you #include <iostream> ?

As a sidenote, that's a weird design. Your template does not save any coding, and just makes things unreadable: instead of "GetName", you are expecting people to call "GetString" and expect them to know that this will be the name. Also, what happens if you add another string to the thing eventually?

if ( needs to be if constexpr (

I'm actually surprised the first call works, and the 2nd one only returning a warning -- without constexpr in the play, it should always complain about two of the three push_back() calls because the types don't match...

@ChristianStieber This is not a real use case. It is a simplified version of something else, just to illustrate the issue.

The problem is in your GetValue() implementation:
The push_back statements are compiled for all the ifs, even if the value you attempt to add does not match the type T of the vector.
Instead you can use if constexpr (requires C++17 on higher), so that the compiler will not compile the branches that do not satisfy the condition:
std::vector<T> GetValue()
{
    std::vector<T> v;

    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)
        v.push_back(age);
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, char>)
        v.push_back(gender);
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
        v.push_back(name);

    return v;
}

A side note:
Your posted code is missing #include <iostream> in order to compile.
